# Grep to select alternate outputs after certain Characters

Tags: linux, bash, logging, grep, output

I have a text file test.txt

```
It has list as follows
Profile Roy
 City: New York
 Age: 78_months
 Sex: Male
Profile Smith
 City: Texas
 Age: 56_months
 Sex: Male
```

What I want is to grep output of Roy and Smith and so on so forth...... such that it should output as

```
78_months New York
56_months Texas
```

What I tried so far didn't work

`grep -l 'Age:|City:' test.txt >> output txt`

Comment: Ifthis is your own project, try to use a standard machine-readable data format like JSON or CSV instead of this unstructured ad-hoc format.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use grep here, look into sed or awk ..

example for awk/sed  well haven't used them in a while ..

```
Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234

Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754


$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} {print $1,$3}' addresses
```

will output

```
Person Name (222) 466-1234
Another person (523) 643-8754
```

so  awk '/Age|City/,1' 
will output

```
 
 City: New York
 Age: 78_months
 City: Texas
 Age: 56_months
```

Then awk  awk '{x = $0; getline; print; print x}'

will switch lines  to

```
 Age: 78_months
 City: New York
 Age: 56_months
 City: Texas
```

so a quickhack is

awk '/Age|City/,1' test | awk '{x = $0; getline; print; print x}'  |  sed  -r 's/Age://g' | sed -r 's/City://g' | xargs -n2 | sed 's/  */ /g'

:P

```
78_months New York
56_months Texas
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
 awk '{print $5, $3}' RS="Profile" FS="[:\n]" input.1.txt
```

#### Output for provided input:

```
$ awk '{print $5, $3}' RS="Profile" FS="[:\n]" input.1.txt
 
 78_months  New York
 56_months  Texas
```

#### Explanation:

`{print $5, $3}`  Print 5th field and 3rd field following by newline.

`RS="Profile"`  Set `awk` record separator to RegExp "Profile"

`FS="[:\n]"`  Set `awk` field separator to char `:` and newline `\n`

Comment: Thanks but this returns only the first instance. It's doesn't give output for second line and rest others.